# retrieve the text value and use it as a parameter in function in xquery

Tags: pattern-matching, xquery

I wish to use the matches function of XQuery on the value of a particular element in a XML document which takes 2 strings as parameters. I need to pass the text value of the element to the function as a parameter. But when I use $title/text() it does not accept it as string and gives an error

Comment: Can you add a small example that reproduces the exact error you're seeing? Also, please add the exact error to your question.

Answer (score 1):

I guess (due to lack of more information...) you intended to do something like:

```
let $doc := <doc>
  <title>Abc</title>
  <title>Cde</title>
  </doc>
for $title in $doc/title
return matches($title, "Cde")
```

and I guess instead, you did something like:

```
let $doc := <doc>
  <title>Abc</title>
  <title>Cde</title>
  </doc>
        (: oh no! :)
let $title := $doc/title
return matches($title, "Cde")
```

This leads to a `$title` variable containing a sequence of *two* `text()` items; but as  [`fn:contains()`](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/fn_contains.html) only accepts `xs:string?` and not `xs:string+` for its arguments it will fail, complaining (e.g. in BaseX) that:

```
[XPTY0004] Single item expected, (<title>...</title>, <title>...</title>) found.
```

Comment: +1 for a very reasonable guess.

Comment: Thanks DevNull! We'll see if Gopal will provide some more information soon (-: